# Can malware brick my computer?

Tags: security, uefi, malware

I have read that [because of UEFI it is possible for malware to brick my computer](https://medium.com/@varunmittal91/101-brick-lenovo-uefi-computer-in-three-easy-steps-ab48acb789d8). By "brick" I mean render the computer's motherboard permanently broken so that it no longer works. Another example, is a case where [an MSI laptop using ESI was bricked after the hard drive was erased](http://thenextweb.com/insider/2016/02/01/running-a-single-delete-command-can-permanently-brick-laptops-from-inside-linux/). Obviously this is a concern because hard drives can fail for all sorts of reason, so you do not to erase it to make it unreadable.

Is this true? If so, is there any way I can pre-empt this from happening (other than getting a computer that does not use UEFI)? Is this phenomenom limited to just particular poorly designed computers like the Lenovo and MSI cited in the examples above, or is it true of all computers?

**Update**

Based on [an article on this issue](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2337180/new-attack-methods-can-brick-systems-defeat-secure-boot-researchers-say.html) linked in a comment to this question, there some partial answers. First, the article makes clear that whether a PC is brickable depends largely on the particular UEFI implementation a particular vendor uses. So, one manufacturer's UEFI might be brickable and anothers might not. According to the same article about half of all current PCs have software-writable UEFI that could be compromised by malware.

Therefore, to prevent this from happening, the user has to evaluate the particular UEFI implementation and determine whether it is software vulnerable.

Comment: That's not really true. You can repair the motherboard with putting a valid uefi on it. Yes, special hardware is needed for this action. So any pc service station can repair your motherboard in minutes.

Comment: That article doesn't explain the entire story.  It was possible before UEFI to brick a computer.  UEFI is simply the new interface.  It's literally called *Unified Extensible Firmware Interface* whereas BIOS stands for *Basic Input/Output System*  There are several optional security features within UEFI that prevent malware from modifying the UEFI itself.

Comment: Maybe this will help?  http://www.pcworld.com/article/2337180/new-attack-methods-can-brick-systems-defeat-secure-boot-researchers-say.html